# Problems recording http requests in Jmeter

Tags: performance, jmeter

I'm trying to record my use of a web application, so that I can replicate it for the purpose of load tests. I've never used JMeter before, so I wanted to start with a simple example.

I follow this tutorial: `http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf` and when I get to step 23 (navigating to a webpage), the page gives me back an error:

```
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://jmeter.apache.org refused at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:190) at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294) at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:643) at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:479) at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906) at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805) at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:481) at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:298) at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74) at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1105) at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.run(Proxy.java:236) Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method) at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:69) at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339) at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200) at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182) at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:157) at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391) at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579) at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:127) at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180) ... 10 more
```

Has anyone seen this problem before? Have I made a mistake in the proxy-config?

At `"step 18. Address – enter “localhost” or the IP address of your system"`
I entered localhost, even though the web app I'm recording (http://jmeter.apache.org/index.html) isn't deployed locally. Is that a mistake?

Can anyone give me more insight?

Answer (score 0):

No this is not a mistake. Enter localhost as your proxy. 
Also make sure your Testscript recorder is actually on and recording.

Comment: Yep, that's how proxy is configured. Test script recorder is set up and recording as well.

Answer (score 0):

Follow The steps mentioned below:

1. Open Commandline.
2. Goto the location where the JMeter files are coppied.
3. Run the following command: jmeter -H proxyname -P 8080 -u username -a password -N localhost (username, password, localhost are optional).
4. This opens JMeter in UI mode.
5. Now, follow usual steps to record the  application.

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind that, as it says in the [user manual](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html):

> Parameters provided on a command-line may be visible to other users on the system.